# Should I create many ID for a same Person/entity in my DB?

Tags: foreign-key, normalization, primary-key, duplication

In my model, I must store the name of the teacher of some kids and the classroom in which the teachers work, let’s say. All of the hundreds of teachers in the schools have 1 and only 1 classroom, except 2 teachers, which have 2 classrooms and there is no way we can remove one classroom (we MUST keep the 2 classrooms)… do you know of a way to handle this exception ? Knowing that it might happen with other teachers in the future.

The only solution I found so far goes as follow:

**Kid Table**

Kid ID (PK)

Teacher ID

**Teacher Table**

Teacher ID (PK)

Teacher Name

Classroom ID

And to have 2 teacher ID (or more) for the very few teachers who have more than 1 classroom. I do need the teacher name in the teacher table to be able to produce stats based on the teachers (no matter the number of teacher ID related to any given teacher).

Does it this model make sense ? is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: Is there any reason not to add a Classroom table? Kid table will have Classroom ID instead of Teacher ID and Classroom table will contain Classroom ID as PK and Teacher ID as FK to Teacher table.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! The problem is that it would then not be normal anymore since the classroom would depend on the teacher, not on the kid (3rd normal form - transitive dependency). Also, there is too much risk that some classroom entry be forgotten for a given teacher during an update and, with the large size of the database, this "duplication" of data would be quite heavy... that's why I am looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Well, seems to me that separating classroom from teacher will be MORE normalization, not less, as you need to have multiple classrooms per teacher, and those kids from the two classrooms of the given teacher each reference only one of those two "teacher-clasroom" objects - thats why you think about duplicating the teacher from what I understand. And "forgotten during the update" will usually happen more with duplicated teacher. With three tables you either duplicate a classroom - one table, or a teacher info - other table and all classes of a given teacher will immediatelly "see" the update.

Comment: HA ! I get it now, it makes total sense ! And it will indeed lead to normal, easy to update and non-duplicated data ! Thank you very much jkavalik :D

Comment: now how do I mark your answer as the "Answer" to my question to close the subject ? you answered in a comment ... :/

Comment: I did not expect to write so much of it to actually stand as an answer ;) will add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly normalized it will have 3 tables as follows:

Kid

```
kid_id (pk)
classroom_id (fk to Classroom)
```

Teacher

```
teacher_id (pk)
name
```

Classroom

```
classroom_id (pk)
teacher_id (fk to teacher)
```

This way you have no duplication and no update anomalies.

Comment: Thank you. (see comments under the question for more details)